# JAVASCRIPT ler um arquivo TXT

Tags: javascript, linux, terminal

Fiz um comando no linux que salva em um txt a saida do terminal de tempos em tempos, no caso a saida do comando **free -m**, queria ler esse arquivo .txt para que o javascript ficasse atualizando os valores periodicamente sem ter que recarregar a página, no caso o retorno do terminal seria algo como:

```
       total    used    free    shared    buff/cache    available
Mem:    2004     998     155       231           850          511
Swap:   4000       0    4000
```

Queria que o Script ao pegar os textos salvassem em um array tipo

Array[0] = "total  used    free shared   buff   available" 
Array[1] = "Mem:    2004   998     155    231    850         511" 
Array[2] = "Swap:   4000     0    4000"

Pois depois disso usaria ***o Array[1].split(" ")*** para separar em outro array contendo cada um dos valores da memoria e ***o Array[2].split(" ")***  contendo cada um dos valores da swap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usando o [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) você consegue ler o arquivo.

```
fetch('arquivo.txt')
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(text => {
    const array = text.split("\n");
    console.log(array);
  })
```

[Aqui um exemplo.](https://plnkr.co/edit/8jqSGKgtx1OY3yg2FFlp?p=preview), veja o array no console.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]